# Google Speech Voice API and database specifications?

Tags: speech-recognition, google-voice

I'm using Google Speech Voice API for a big project ; as you understand i need to use voice recognition in an input, I built it this way :

```
<input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="200" x-webkit-speech lang="fr" onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();">
```

It works. It recognize your voice and try to put something. My problem is it doesn't understand anything because it certainly takes Google database as reference to understand what you're saying.

I want to set my database as reference instead and get good recognition, but after a few hours searching a solution on Internet I didn't find it.

I tried to understand how GRXML works (because you can add it to set some specifications on inputs) - i gave up as well, i didn't even get the point about this thing.

Is someone has experience in voice recognition and could help me about this ? There's almost no documentation on Internet about voice recognition and database link (or even XML file, i could generate it).

Comment: And i'm like "Why can't anybody see my post ?" ... Even me when i'm searching it i don't find.